# Update/Select rows of successive pattern

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I update a column in a table to follow a specific pattern ?
Currently my DesiredResultAfterUpdate is empty and I want to set it so that it would be 1,2,3 for IDs 1,2,3. Then it would be 1,2,3 for the next set of IDs, (IDs4,5,6 and 7,8,9 and so on)?

```
ID DesiredResultAfterUpdate Name
1  1                        My First Row
2  2                        My 2nd Row
3  3                        My Third Row
4  1                        My Forth Row
5  2                        My Fifth Row
6  3                        My Next Row
7  1                        My 7th Row
8  2                        etc
9  3                        etc
```

So far I tried

```
UPDATE coins set coin_Row = 1
UPDATE coins set coin_Row = 2 where coin_SortOrder%2=0
UPDATE coins set coin_Row = 3 where coin_SortOrder%3=0
```

Which only worked for every 3rd item ... (Shocking)

Comment: Is `coin_SortOrder` an alias for `ID`? Is it always guaranteed to start at 1 and be dense, i.e. have no missing values?

Comment: @HABO Starts from one, but has a few missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will do what you want, using your UPDATE queries as an example:

```
UPDATE coins
SET coin_Row = (coin_SortOrder-1) % 3 + 1;
```

Comment: That's better than my solution, you have avoided the CASE statement.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

How's this:

```
UPDATE  Coins
SET     Coin_Row = CASE WHEN coin_SortOrder%3 = 0 THEN 3 ELSE coin_SortOrder%3 END
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started for ranking over N records. N is set to 3 below.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID INT)
INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)

WITH T AS (
SELECT 
  ID,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RANK
FROM 
  TEST
)
SELECT 
  ID, 
  (RANK - 1) / 3 GROUP_ID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (RANK - 1) / 3 ORDER BY ID) AS ROWNUM
FROM 
  T
GROUP BY 
  ((RANK - 1) / 3), ID
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will update the `CoinRow` column in `Id` order to 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... . The starting value of `Id` and missing values will not effect the sequence.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Coins as Table ( Id Int, CoinRow Int NULL );
insert into @Coins ( Id ) values
  ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ),
  ( 4 ), ( 6 ), ( 7 ),
  ( 10 ), ( 11 ), ( 12 ),
  ( 19 );
select * from @Coins;

-- Update the   CoinRow   column.
with CoinRows as (
  select Id, CoinRow, ( Row_Number() over ( order by Id ) - 1 ) % 3 + 1 as NewCoinRow
    from @Coins )
update CoinRows
  set CoinRow = NewCoinRow;
select * from @Coins;
```